What do these do?

These look like they need replacing, what do they do and how much do they cost.
Also my heating isn't working properly is this why?

Please clarify. Are these rusty valves connected to your heating system's pipes?

Please a photo of the whole setup.

They are shut off valves.
They stop water/fluids from moving when turned off, which might be difficult with how they look.
They are mainly for maintenance work so water can be turned off and not flow out when pipes need replacing.
Unless those valves are blocked inside, your heating problems are probably due to another problem.
An HVAC technician might be the best to fix any heating problem and check those valves.

They look like tank isolation valves or zone gate valves which regulate the heat flow to different areas of the house. The problem with this type of valve is that the gate corrodes and doesn't close completely or you close it and the threads strip due to corrosion and the valve won't open which would cause low or no heat. There is a lot of rust showing where the pipes go into the valves at the top. This needs no be looked at more closely and yes, replaced. We don't do costs on this site because it varies according th areas.
